# After install and uninstall a package, python3 crashes with error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, segmentation-fault, tensorflow2.0

The steps leading to the problem is as follows:

1. I installed a package using pip. The package is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics) and its install doc is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics/blob/master/tensorflow_graphics/g3doc/install.md). The command I used is

   pip install --upgrade tensorflow-graphics-gpu

Because I don't have super user privilege, the package was installed in my user space. pip prompted me for that.

2. I uninstalled the package using

   pip uninstall tensorflow-graphics-gpu
3. I started python3 and type

   import tensorflow as tf

This statement worked fine before. But this time, python quits with an error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is a screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/babqJ.png).

The environment is as follows:

1. A remote Linux. Core version 5.8.0. I am not not a super user.
2. Python 3.8.6
3. CUDA 11.1
4. CPU: Core i9-10900K
5. nVidia RTX GPU

The same error crashes python if I tried to import PyTorch. The sys admin is very disagreeable so I can get no help from him, not to mention upgrading drivers or reinstalling python. I tried to clear cashes in my user space that I know of, but I didn't have luck. I searched internet for a solution but of no avail.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to clear cashes in my user space that I know of, but I didn't have luck.

It seems pretty clear that *something* in your `$HOME` directory is still being used, and is causing the system `python` to crash.

To discover what that something is, you can look at which files are being opened using this command:

```
strace -e file python -c 'import tensorflow'
```

Once you know which files are being opened, remove/reinstall corresponding packages, and you should be back in business.

Comment: Thank you. Your method works. As a side note, strace seems not working with less or output redirection in the remote Linux, but last few lines of its output suffice. The cache files I failed to clear is in ~/.local. After cleaning this folder, tensorflow can now be imported without any problem. A side effect I did not want however is that PyTorch is broken with error "ImportError: libtorch_cuda_cu.so". I think that's because caches in that folder related to PyTorch were also cleared. But that should not be a big issue for me. I'll try to fix it myself. Thank you again for your help.